# Excluding string from changes in sed

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I want to make a sed command to change strings that each comma separated part will be in double quotes. The problem is that some values have already double quotes.

Change from:

```
ABZ00016,ABZ,"449,9",450,445,449,"-0,21",405,13,"182,15",0,0,0
```

to

```
"ABZ00016","ABZ","449,9","450","445","449","-0,21","405","13","182,15","0","0","0"
```

I prepared two sed commands:

First command excludes values with double quotes

```
sed -e 's/"[^"]*"//g'
```

Second adds double quotes to each part

```
 sed  -e 's/\([^,]*\),/"\1",/g'
```

And now I wanted to exclude results from first command and make changes using second command:

```
 sed -e '/"[^"]*"/!s/\([^,]*\),/"\1",/g'
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: Do you have to use `sed` only? Are you fine with `perl` or `awk` as well?

Comment: If you have solution in awk I will be grateful :-)

Comment: I've posted a gnu-awk solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed with regex mate:

```
sed -r -e 's/[-.a-zA-Z0-9]+/"&"/g' -e 's/""/"/g'
```

Edit: Updated to Your request, works as expected:

```
sed -r -e 's/"([^,]+)(,)([0-9]+)"/\1\.\3/g' -e 's/[-.a-zA-Z0-9]+/"&"/g' -e 's/""/"/g' -e 's/\./,/g'
```

Comment: Hi Filip, I used your command but I get "449","9", instead of "449,9"

Comment: This will now wreck any full stops, and still doesn't handle quoted strings correctly.

Comment: Thank you Filip! I started use your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using `gnu-awk` you can do this:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' -v OFS=, '{
   for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      gsub(/^"|"$/, "", $i)
      $i = "\"" $i "\""
   }
} 1' file
```

**Output:**

```
"ABZ00016","ABZ","449,9","450","445","449","-0,21","405","13","182,15","0","0","0"
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^/\n/;:a;s/\n$//;s/\n("[^"]*",?)/\1\n/;s/\n([^,]*)(,?)/"\1"\2\n/;ta' file
```

Introduce a newline as a marker then: remove the marker when all fields have been processed, skip over quoted fields and surround other fields with quotes. With each substitution advance the marker down the line.